# PHP variable transfer from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, html, phaser-framework

I am building a game on html5(phaser js) for which i need to build a leaderboard. the code snippet is this:

```
restart_game: function() {  
// Start the 'main' state, which restarts the game
//this.game.time.events.remove(this.timer);  
    //this.game.time.events.remove(this.timer2);  
    //this.game.state.start('main');
    var string="score.php?score="+this.score;
    window.open(string);
},
```

in the window.open function i wish to pass the value of score to another page where i will ask for the player's name and then insert both the score and the name to the database. But i am having trouble passing the score value across three pages. 
How can i do this? Do I need AJAX or just PHP and Javascript is sufficient?

Comment: In PHP you can use $_GET to get the score value...http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use browser cookie? you can save score value in cookie and access it whenever you need? Read this on how to use cookies link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

To save to cookie like this:

```
document.cookie="score=54; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT";
```

In PHP you can read cookie

```
if(isset(($_COOKIE['score'])) {
    $score = $_COOKIE['score'];
}
```

To Read cookie in JS:

```
var score = document.cookie;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the session variable for keeping the variable in the memory and it will be accessible untill your session is alive.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['session'])) {
    $session = eval("return {$_POST['session']};");
    if (is_array($session)) {
        $_SESSION = $session;
        header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?saved");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?error");
    }
}

$session = htmlentities(var_export($_SESSION, true));
?>
```

For more information look here [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Eval? Why..? var_export?

Comment: var_export — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable.  <?php
$a = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
var_export($a);
?>
The above example will output:

array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
  ),
)

Answer (score 1):

Find [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
restart_game: function() {  
  var score = this.score;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'save_score.php',
    data: {score: score},
    method: 'POST'
  }).done(function() {
    window.location = "other_page.php";
  });
},
```

save_score.php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['score']) && strlen($_POST['score']) > 0) {
  $score = intval($_POST['score']);
  $_SESSION['score'] = $score;
}
```

other_page.php

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_SESSION variable in php to keep track of user related data in a session. It requires cookies.